# Count If A or B but with no doublecounting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a group of cells that have strings of indicating various statements. I need it to count the cells uniquely if it has (For example) ABC, ABD, or ABQ however one cell could read " ABC ABD AMN" and that would need to be counted only once. The order is not standard.

When looking I only found the suggestion to use a "CountIf(ABC) + CountIf(ABD)+CountIf(ABQ), but that would double count multiple cells.

Then CountIfs(ABC,ABD,ABQ) counts only cells that include all of those. What method can I use to uniquely count the cells without double counting?

```
Set j = .Range(Cells(s, 8), Cells(e, 8))
    .Cells(s - 1, 8).Value = Application.WroksheetFunction.CountIfs(j, "* ABC*", j, "*ABD*", j, "*ABQ*")
```

So the input cells might be

```
 [ACD AQM AFD ABD]
 [ABM ARQ ABQ ABC]
 [AAA ABE ARQ]
```

And the output would be 2.Since two of the cells have at least one of the required phrases (ABC,ABD,ABQ). CountIfs would mistakenly give 0. CountIf + CountIf would mistakenly give 3.

Comment: An example of your input and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: Edited it with an example at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
Set j = .Range(.Cells(s, 8), .Cells(e, 8))
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    .Cells(s - 1, 8).Value = .COUNTIF(j,"*ABC*") + .COUNTIF(j,"*ABD*") - .COUNTIFS(j,"*ABC*",j,"*ABD*")
End With
```

Comment: This is perfect! For anybody looking later keep in mind that for three (ABC,ABD,ABQ) it will expand to.`(ABC)+(ABD)+(ABQ) - (ABC & ABD)-(ABC & ABQ)-(ABD & ABQ)-(ABC & ABD & ABQ).`

Comment: @EmilyAlden if this is the method by which you solved your problem please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do it, may need optimization if you're working with very large column of data. The idea is to check each cell against each of the ABC, ABD, or ABQ, and exit the loop early if a matching value is found in the cell. This should prevent double-counting of cells that might match on more than one criteria.

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim word, words, val, vals
words = CountedWords
Set rng = Range("A1:A3")  'Modify as needed
vals = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)

For Each val In vals
    For Each word In words
        If InStr(val, word) Then
            i = i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
MsgBox i
End Sub

Function CountedWords()
    CountedWords = Array("ABC", "ABD", "ABQ") 'Modify as needed
End Function
```